# What is the best logic to create filtering system in CMS, and then to add option to choose how many filtered results will be shown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am building CMS for a blog and I added option to filter posts on admin dashboard. Options are published posts, draft posts, commented posts and most viewed posts. 
Here is the code

```
<?php
function get_options($select){

$filters = array('All posts' => 1, 'Published Posts' => 2, 'Drafted Posts' => 3, 'Commented Posts' => 4, 'Most Viewed Posts' => 5);

$options = '';

foreach($filters as $k => $v) {
    if($select == $v){
        $options.='<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$k.'</option>';
    } else {

        $options.='<option value="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</option>';
    }
}

return $options;

}

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="filter">

    <div id="bulkOptionsContainer" class="col-xs-3">

        <select class="form-control" name="filter_posts" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="">Filter Posts</option>
            <?php echo get_options($selected); ?>
        </select><br>

    </div>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filter_posts'])) {

            $filter_posts = $_POST['filter_posts'];

            switch ($filter_posts) {

                case '1';

                    include_once("all_posts.php"); //Here is query for all posts from database

                    break;

                case '2';

                   include_once("published_posts.php"); //Here is query for published posts from database

                    break;


                case '3';

                    include_once("draft_posts.php"); //Here is code for drafted posts from database

                    break;

                case '4';

                    include_once("commented_posts.php");//Here is query for commented posts from database

                    break;

                case '5';

                   include_once("most_viewed_posts.php");//Here is query for most viewed posts from database


                    break;
            }
        }
?>
```

This works for me, and I get all wanted results, but I want do add a functionality to select how many results will be displayed on a page. For example show 20 posts, show 40 posts, show all posts. But it needs to show, for example, if I filter posts to published posts, and select show 20 posts, it needs to show 20 posts for published posts, etc. How to do this?
Here is HTML for select options.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="bulkOptionsContainer" class="col-xs-2">
        <select name="select_num_posts" class="form-control">

            <option value="20" selected>Show 20</option>
            <option value="40">Show 40</option>
            <option value="all">Show All</option>

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Apply">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make many more PHP files, called `draft_posts_20.php`, `draft_posts_40.php` and `draft_posts_all.php`, etc, but that would create many, many files. Clearly this approach is flawed.

I assume that each of these files, `all_posts.php`, `draft_posts.php`, etc, contain very similar code. There's a database query and some output code. They are basically copies of each other, with a slight variation.

I think you should try to put them all into one PHP file, and then also incorporate your new filter. The output part should be the same for all of them, it's just the database query you need to vary, based on your two filters.

Comment: Yes, actually I have it all together on one page and like this on another. I was thinking which way is better. Thanks for clearing it up. But my problem is how to incorporate new filter, and that filter needs to be related to previous filter. Basically when I filter posts to show only published, how to relate select options show 20 or show 40 only to published posts. What logic do I need to use? I am guessing I need to use some javascript code.

Comment: I think you should try and solve this in PHP. However, that code is missing from your question, so I can't give any detailed advice. The idea is: You have two filters to form the query to retrieve information for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code from single page version. This way I am managing to filter posts, but I dont know how to filter filtered posts, to show 20, 40 etc.

```
<?php
    function get_options($select){

        $filters = array('All posts' => 1, 'Published Posts' => 2, 'Drafted Posts' => 3, 'Commented Posts' => 4, 'Most Viewed Posts' => 5);

        $options = '';

        foreach($filters as $k => $v) {
            if($select == $v){
                $options.='<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$k.'</option>';
            } else {

                $options.='<option value="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</option>';
            }
        }

        return $options;

    }

    function get_num_options($select){

        $filters = array('Show 20' => 20, 'Show 40' => 40, 'Show All' => 'all');

        $options = '';

        foreach($filters as $k => $v) {
            if($select == $v){
                $options.='<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$k.'</option>';
            } else {

                $options.='<option value="'.$v.'">'.$k.'</option>';
            }
        }

        return $options;

    }

?>    
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="filter">

        <div id="bulkOptionsContainer" class="col-xs-3">

            <select class="form-control" name="filter_posts" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="">Filter Posts</option>
                <?php echo get_options($selected); ?>
            </select><br>

        </div>

    </form>

<?php    
      if (!isset($_POST['filter_posts'])) {


                    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                    //Bind
                    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                    //Execute
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                    //Result
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                    confirmQuery($stmt1);

                    $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                    //Bind
                    //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                    //Execute
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                    //Result
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                    confirmQuery($stmt2);

                    if (is_admin()) {

                        $stmt = $stmt1;
                    } else {

                        $stmt = $stmt2;
                    }
                } else {

                    $filter_posts = $_POST['filter_posts'];

                    switch ($filter_posts) {

                        case '1';

                            $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt1);

                            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt2);

                            if (is_admin()) {

                                $stmt = $stmt1;
                            } else {

                                $stmt = $stmt2;
                            }

                            break;

                        case '2';

                            $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.comment_status = ? ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $comment_status);

                            $comment_status = 'published';
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt1);

                            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.comment_status = ? AND posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $comment_status);

                            $comment_status = 'published';
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt2);

                            if (is_admin()) {

                                $stmt = $stmt1;
                            } else {

                                $stmt = $stmt2;
                            }

                            break;


                        case '3';

                            $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.comment_status = ? ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $comment_status);

                            $comment_status = 'draft';
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt1);

                            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.comment_status = ? AND posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $comment_status);

                            $comment_status = 'draft';
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt2);

                            if (is_admin()) {

                                $stmt = $stmt1;
                            } else {

                                $stmt = $stmt2;
                            }

                            break;

                        case '4';

                            $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.post_comment_count > 0 ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();

                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt1);

                            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.post_comment_count > 0 AND posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_id DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt2);

                            if (is_admin()) {

                                $stmt = $stmt1;
                            } else {

                                $stmt = $stmt2;
                            }

                            break;

                        case '5';

                            $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id ORDER BY post_views_count DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt1);

                            $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_author, posts.post_user, posts.post_title, posts.post_category_id, posts.comment_status, posts.post_image, posts.post_tags, posts.post_comment_count, posts.post_date, posts.post_views_count, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_title FROM posts LEFT JOIN categories ON posts.post_category_id = categories.cat_id WHERE posts.user_id = " . loggedInUserId() . " ORDER BY post_views_count DESC");

                            //Bind
                            //mysqli_stmt_bind_param();
                            //Execute
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
                            //Result
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $post_id, $post_author, $post_user, $post_title, $post_category_id, $comment_status, $post_image, $post_tags, $post_comment_count, $post_date, $post_views_count, $cat_id, $cat_title);

                            confirmQuery($stmt2);

                            if (is_admin()) {

                                $stmt = $stmt1;
                            } else {

                                $stmt = $stmt2;
                            }



                            break;
                    }
                }

                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

                   //Echo result
                }



                ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="filter">

        <div id="bulkOptionsContainer" class="col-xs-3">

            <select class="form-control" name="select_num_posts" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="">Show Posts</option>
                <?php echo get_num_options($selected); ?>
            </select><br>

        </div>

    </form>
```